# Mac crashes/reboots if I get a ton of notifications at once while asleep

Tags: google-chrome, crash, notifications

I'm unsure if this is a mac issue or a browser issue, I suspect the former so I'll try here first.

In short, I have a few browser applications that generate desktop notifications. If I lock my mac and within a short span of time, ~45 seconds or less, over 4 notifications appear, the computer won't wake. Once when I walked away, it had even rebooted itself by the time I got back, but I have not been able to replicate this. I don't know if non-browser generated notifications cause the same problem.

This is not a problem while the mac is unlocked.

I'm using a Macbook Pro 15" 2015 running Sierra (10.12.6). My browser is Chrome 65.

I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me as to what is breaking and how I can fix it, or inform me if this is the browser and definitely not a mac issue.

Comment: Can you turn on notifications in say safari or firefox and replicate this issue using another browser?

Comment: Firefox and Safari are really sluggish about it, but it will wake up again. This inclines me to think that the excess of notifications is choking the memory and preventing the mac from waking. I'm still unsure if this is a mac issue or a chrome issue, in that I'm not sure which I'll have to change to fix the issue.